# lxml parse url ampersand issue

Tags: python, lxml

I have an url which looks something like this:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/?q=abc%26def&other_params=here'
```

Accessing this url in a browser an xml will be returned.

I am trying to parse the response of that url through lxml:

```
tree = etree.parse(url)
```

The problem here is that etree encodes the percent char and the url will be

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/?q=abc%2526def&other_params=here'
```

If I dont encode the value of my q parameter, the whole url gets messed up:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/?q=abc&def&other_params=here'
```

Is there any way I can tell lxml not to enocde the chars in that url before sending out the request?

Comment: Sounds like an lxml bug; have you tried [reporting](https://launchpad.net/lxml/) it?

Comment: not really but I will do that in case someone doesnt come with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that's a bug in lxml's URL handling, you should check for existing reports in the [lxml tracker](https://launchpad.net/lxml/), and report it if it isn't there yet.

The work-around for now is to use `urllib2` to retrieve your URL instead:

```
import urllib2

resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
tree = etree.parse(resp)
```

Comment: instead of using `urllib2`, I rather like `requests` .. it does url encoding (in case if needed in GET request) and all the stuff automatically..

Comment: @Surya: Sure, but that's an extra dependency. The OP clearly already knows how to urlencode, in which case `urllib2` more than suffices.